# Getting undefined while iterating through _.each in underscorejs template with backbonejs

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, codeigniter-restserver

I am fetching the JSON using the library philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver
When I check in the response section of console, I get the proper JSON values returned like

```
this: [{name:test,address:test},{name:test2,address:test2}].
```

On fronted I want these values to be displayed in the template. But it just returns `{"readyState":1}` when I do `<%= JSON.stringify(ledgers) %>`.

I call the template from my view like this:

```
$("#container-left").html(this.template({ledgers:app.ledgers.fetch()}));
```

My REST controller function looks like:

```
public function index_get()
{

    $this->response($this->db->get('ledgers')->result());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your aren't using the `fetch` method correctly. Because `fetch`  doesn't return the data when it is called so you need to provide the `success` callback to fill your template:

```
var self = this;
app.ledgers.fetch({
    success: function(model, response, options) {
        $("#container-left").html(self.template({ledgers: model}));
    }
});
```

The `_.each` function itself won't return anything so you when you output the return value you get undefinied.

You need to output the data inside your function with `<%= name %>`

```
<% _.each(ledgers, function(data){  %> <%= name %> <% }) %>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yfr4g/).

Comment: ok that throws me a nasty error which i think is solely because of not knowing the ledgers object. Is there a way i can see the structure of the ledger object as i am fetching it from some remote source?

Comment: When you generating the template you can specify a variable name where you can access the whole object what is passed in the template as the data. Then you can output the current context in your template: see http://jsfiddle.net/yh6kp/. Or just debug your fetching code to see how is the returned data look like.

Comment: I only get this {"readyState":1} when i do a JSON.stringify(ledgers). But when i check response headers, i am getting the full correct json data.

Comment: Ok then your `ledgers` is not a collection so you don't need the each: to write out the value you need `<%= ledgers.readyState %>` which will outputs 1.

Comment: I need to fetch json that i receive from the backend and display in frontend. Backend returns the right data. Here is what i receive from backend: [{name:test,address:test},{name:test2,address:test2}]. I want to iterate over this JSON.

Comment: @MrinalPurohit You are now far away from you original question. You should extend (or better create a new) question with your current problem: how is your template looks like, how do you generate the template, and how is the data looks like which you use for the template.

Comment: Yes now i got it. Just wanted to know that as we have used the self variable for scope issues, is there a better way to do this? Or this approach is fine? Thanks a ton for your help though.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23208/discussion-between-mrinal-purohit-and-nemesv)